# How to clamp font size using TailwindCSS?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, clamp

How can the `clamp()` CSS function be used with TailwindCSS to make the `fontSize` linearly scale between a min and a max value?

Interested in particular about integrating with Next.js.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the time of writing, TailwindCSS doesn't seem to support `clamp()` natively by default.

Search returns a use case on [multi-line truncation using the `line-clamp` plugin](https://tailwindcss.com/blog/multi-line-truncation-with-tailwindcss-line-clamp), which is different from clamping font sizes.

Taking inspiration from [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/2638), using `clamp()` in TailwindCSS can be accomplished by extending the default theme. Example in a Next.js app:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",

    // Or if using `src` directory:
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontSize: {
        clamp: "clamp(1rem, 5vw, 3rem)",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

To use it in a `jsx` or `tsx` component, one can just pass `text-clamp` as an additional `className`.

[image]

Link to [working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/wonderful-kare-tkko3i?file=%2Fpages%2Findex.tsx&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A1%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A4%2C%22startColumn%22%3A1%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A4%7D%5D).

Comment: This method doesn't allow changing the values inside the clamp

Answer (score 5):

There is no Tailwind utility class to do this easily but you can do this by writing custom CSS with [Arbitrary properties](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#arbitrary-properties)

Example:

```html
<h1 class="[font-size:_clamp(2em,5vw,10em)]">Text</h1>
```